# eXplainable Artificial Intelligence (XAI). Need help building a XAI model to explain the results of an IDS classifier

Tags: neural-network, keras, mlp, ai, explainable-ai

I need some help building a XAI model with Keras to explain the results of an MLP working as an IDS. I have resarched about XAI but the only thing I find is small portions of code that just use existing python libraries. If anyone could help me or give me any advice it would be really helpful, I have been stuck with this project for too long.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards.